# Error passing multiple route parameters in a url path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to fetch data based on the value of 3 fields ("nkk", "nik" and "nama").

voters-ctrl :

```js
getVotersByParams = async (req, res) => {
        const nkk = req.params.nkk
        const nik = req.params.nik
        const nama = req.params.nama

    await Voter.find({nkk, nik, nama}, (err, voters) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
        }
        if (!voters.length) {
            return res
                .status(404)
                .json({ success: false, request: req.params, error: `Voter not found` })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: voters })
    }
}
```

There is possibilities that one or two of them is empty or not defined by user. The problem is passing multiple paramaters in the url route returns "not found" result when one of the parameters is empty (or not defined) :

voters-router:

```js
const express = require('express')

const VotersCtrl = require('../controllers/voters-ctrl')

const router = express.Router()

router.get('/votersbyparams/:nkk/:nik/:nama', VotersCtrl.getVotersByParams)

module.exports = router
```

The succesfull query result :
[image]

The "not found" query result when the "nkk" parameter is empty :
[image]

How can I solve this problem? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: where do you get the error?

Comment: It's not an error, actually. What the user is trying to do is to find the data on the database based on multiple parameters. But, there will be a case where one of the parameters is not entered by user in the input text, which means the user wants to find all data in all not-entered fields/not-specified parameters that match the entered/specified parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with using query string rather than multiple route parameters.

Function that handle the search button :

```
const handleFindClick = async () => {
     const payload = { nkk, nik, nama }
     setIsLoading(true)
     const voters = await api.getVotersByParams(payload)
     setVoters(voters.data.data)
     setIsLoading(false)
     console.log(voters)
    }
```

The payload data is sending to this api route :

```
export const getVotersByParams = (payload) => api.get(`/votersbyparams nkk=${payload.nkk}&nik=${payload.nik}&nama=${payload.nama}`)
```

Finally, a `getVotersByParams` function that executed in the server :

```
getVotersByParams = async (req, res) => {
    const {nkk, nik, nama} = req.query
    await Voter.find({nkk : nkk.length > 0 ? nkk : {$exists : true}, nik : nik.length > 0 ? nik : {$exists : true}, nama : nama.length > 0 ? nama : {$exists : true}}, (err, voters) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
        }
        if (!voters.length) {
            return res
                .status(404)
                .json({ success: false, error: `Voter not found` })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: voters })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case when one of values can be `undefined` or empty you should pass all these values in [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) rather than parts of route. Query string gives you an possibility to pass only some values.

Read [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.query) documentation to get an idea how to read these values from query string.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I combine it with using ternary operators like this : `Voter.find({nkk : nkk.length > 0 ? nkk : {$exists : true}, nik : nik.length > 0 ? nik : {$exists : true}, nama : nama.length > 0 ? nama : {$exists : true}}, (err, voters) =>`, and it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

To use URL Params as you are (i.e. with `req.params`) you need to specify them in the URL as follows:

```js
// Browser
fetch(`${apiRoot}/votersby?nkk=${arg1}&nik=${arg3}&nama=${arg3}`)

// Server
router.get(`/votersby`, (req, res) => {
   const { nkk, nik, nama } = req.params
   console.log({ nkk, nik, nama })
   // ...
})
```

Effectively you are supposed to be using the same endpoint, with different query parameters.

The way you are currently specifying them would actually, conventionally be for:

A) IDs (if there is one `/:id`
B) Looks more like dynamic path (route) building, which you will get 404's for if some of the dynamically generated routes are not found in the API.

See below for more info for specifying a string of parameters:

https://javascript.info/url

Comment: Thank you for your help. I combine it with using ternary operators like this : `Voter.find({nkk : nkk.length > 0 ? nkk : {$exists : true}, nik : nik.length > 0 ? nik : {$exists : true}, nama : nama.length > 0 ? nama : {$exists : true}}, (err, voters) =>`, and it works perfect.